# Broken link between aspx and aspx.cs files

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I've had the same problem a couple of times with different ASPX pages after renaming them and I am surprised that I can't find someone else with the same problem on stackoverflow.

When I run my ASP.NET C# project, the debugger gives me a message like this one.

```
Error   5   The name 'txtTitle' does not exist in the current context
```

It seems that the aspx and aspx.cs files at no longer bound. The only fix I have found for this is to recreate the page and copy/paste my code.

Any idea how to fix this without recreating the whole thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code file contains a partial class that is referenced in the ASPX header declaration. Both file name and the actual class in the ASPX header have to match for this to work.

```
<%@ Page Title="TestPage" Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestPage" %>
```

In your case probably the class name does not match. Check if the class name in the codebehind .cs file matches the name after **Inherits**.

The concept of partial classes used in ASP.NET is detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178138.aspx).

Comment: Just found out that I was missing the namespace of my page's class in the inherit attribute. I'll be sure to look at this the next time it happens to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised at this occurring I regularly rename Silverlight user controls with no harmful side-effects.

Are all of the references to classes being renamed in the aspx page and code behind ?

You might try using [this util](http://jfromaniello.blogspot.com/2010/10/introducing-my-new-visual-studio.html) to relink them.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be caused by the `whatever.aspx.designer.vb` file being dependent upon `whatever.aspx.vb` instead of `whatever.aspx`.  If this is the case, it should show incorrectly in the file tree when you expand the group of files in Visual Studio.  To fix it, simply exclude the affected files from the project and then re-include them - the faulty project config file should be regenerated and it should now work correctly.

(Same theory for C#.)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and noticed that sometimes, but not always, the `CodeFile` setting in the `.aspx` page is not updated when the class is changed.  If this is the same problem you have, you can change it manually:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyClass.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyClass" %>
                                                        ^^^^^^^
```