# CodeBehind C# The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I'm building a web site in Visual Studio 2012, using C#. My problem is that one of my controls (a listbox named ListBox1) is not found in CodeBehind. I get the following message:

> The name ListBox1 does not exist in the current context

In my file login.aspx

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

In my file login.aspx.se

```
protected void LoadListBox()
{  
                for (int x = 1; x <= 50; x++)
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Add("Item " + x.ToString());
                }
 }
```

In my file login.aspx.designers.cs

```
/// <summary>
        /// ListBox1 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox ListBox1;
```

I can't even double click on the item to get into CodeBehind.
What can I do? Thank  you for your help

Comment: Everything seems fine... have you tried restarting visual studio?

Comment: I just tried that, but it is still not working. Thank you

Comment: You could also try deleting the designer.cs file and have VS recreate it with "convert to web application" option

Comment: I have also tried that. Thank you.

Comment: Simular question with answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029467/broken-link-between-aspx-and-aspx-cs-files)

Comment: The first line looks like this:
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

Should I change the last letters, after Inherits?

Comment: Thank you Hatsjoem. It now works thanks to your link. The solution was I had to change the word after Inherits from WebApplication1.WebForm1 to WebApplication1.login. See below.
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>